# How can I prove this using inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have to prove that if  $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$, then $u = 0$.

I thought about this:

$\langle u,v \rangle = 0$

$\langle u,v \rangle = \langle 0,v \rangle$

$ u = 0 $

I'm almost sure that this is very wrong, but it was the only way that I could use to prove it.

I think the problem is a little weird as well, because $u=0$ to any $v$. However, if $v = 0$, then $u$ doesn't have to be equals to zero necessarily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get your quantifiers right, the way you wrote it in the question is wrong. The correct thing is *if $\langle u,v\rangle =0$ for all $v$, then $u=0$*. The "for all $v$" comes before the conclusion, as it is an *assumption*. That said, the proof is very simple: if $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all $v$, you're allowed to choose $v=u$. That $\langle u,u\rangle = 0$ implies $u=0$ is one of the axioms in the definition of inner product, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already change it to the correct way. You're right, the exercise used for all $v$ before, I changed to "any $v$" because I didn't notice that it would make difference. Actually, my original exercise have an comma right before "for all $v$", that why I thought it was part of the conclusion, but I was wrong.